# How to show as default the second class in jquery and not All on every page load

Tags: jquery

How can i have on every page load only the  items of the second class  (data-color="Blue") instead of all items?

JSFiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/Cr2cY/

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#filterOptions li a').click(function () {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourDataAttr = $(this).data('color');
    // reset the active class on all the buttons
    $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on our clicked button
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    if (ourDataAttr == 'All') {
        // show all our items
        $('#content').find('.item').show();
    } else {
        // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item:not([data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"])').hide();
        // show all elements that do share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item[data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="filterOptions">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="All" data-color="All">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="Blue" data-color="Blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="Red" data-color="Red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="Black" data-color="Black">Black</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="White" data-color="White">White</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li class="item Blue" data-color="Blue">Blue 1</li>
        <li class="item Blue" data-color="Blue">Blue 2</li>
        <li class="item Red" data-color="Red">Red 1</li>
        <li class="item Red" data-color="Red">Red 2</li>
        <li class="item Black" data-color="Black">Black 1</li>
        <li class="item Black" data-color="Black">Black 2</li>
        <li class="item White" data-color="White">White 1</li>
        <li class="item White" data-color="White">White 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to show only "Blue" when the page loads and not all? Is that?

Comment: Yes, "blue" only.The "category Blue" selected an all its items.

Comment: I just used $('#filterOptions a.Blue').click(); and it works fine.Tnx all for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute `click()`*<sup>[[jQuery]](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click)</sup>* for the default item in your `$(document).ready`:

```
$('#filterOptions a.Blue').click();
```

This triggers the click event for that item, hiding all but Blue items in this case, as if a user had clicked it. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tFA2S/).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... the question is about showing only BLUE when the page loads..

Answer (score 1):

This would be the fastest way:

```
$(".Blue").click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cr2cY/6/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... the question is about showing only BLUE when the page loads..

Comment: This will do it: .click() invokes a fake click event which runs the callback in the context of the "clicked" item, so it'll just use his already existing logic to achieve it. try the fiddle and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question corrctly, you want only to show BLUE items and not all when the page loads. If so try this below.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Purus/Cr2cY/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#content').find('.item:not([data-color="Blue"])').hide();

 $('#filterOptions li a').click(function () {
    // fetch the class of the clicked item
    var ourDataAttr = $(this).data('color');
    // reset the active class on all the buttons
    $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
    // update the active state on our clicked button
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    if (ourDataAttr == 'All') {
        // show all our items
        $('#content').find('.item').show();
    } else {
        // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item:not([data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"])').hide();
        // show all elements that do share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item[data-color="' + ourDataAttr + '"]').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

});